# SharedPreferences save change text size in textview

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a problem with SharedPreferences, there is an AlertDialog with 3 default text sizes. When I click on one of the 3 sizes, the text to TextView is neatly enlarged or reduced, but I need to keep the selected size in SharedPreferences even after I leave the app and return to the app again. Can you help me where I am wrong in my code? Thanks.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CreateAlertDialogWhitRadioGroupButton();
        }

    });


}

public void CreateAlertDialogWhitRadioGroupButton() {

    Context context;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Title text");
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(values, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                    SavePreferences("SIZE", textView.toString());
                    LoadPreferences();

            switch (item) {
                case 0:
                    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 30);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 40);
                    break;
            }
            alertDialogTextSize.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialogTextSize = builder.create();
    alertDialogTextSize.show();
}


// SharedPreferences
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

private void LoadPreferences()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String textsize = sharedPreferences.getString("SIZE", "");
    textView.setTextSize(Float.parseFloat(textsize));

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0q6a.png)

Comment: Have you tried adding a `LoadPreferences()` call to your `onCreate`?

Comment: Yes, but when i call LoadPreferences() to onCreate, app crashed

Comment: What error shows in your log when it crashes?

Comment: you should call getSharedPreferences("prefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) instead of getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `singleton class` for `SharedPreference` and then you can `reuse` it from anywhere.

```
public class SessionManager {
  private static SessionManager jInstance;
  private final SharedPreferences prefs;
  private final SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

  private SessionManager(Context context) {
      prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Your_Preference_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      editor = prefs.edit();
  }

  public static synchronized SessionManager getInstance(Context context) {
      if (jInstance != null) {
          return jInstance;
      } else {
          jInstance = new SessionManager(context);
          return jInstance;
      }
  }

  public void setTextSize(int textSize){
      editor.putInt("text_size",textSize);
      editor.apply();
  }
  public int getTextSize(){
      return prefs.getInt("text_size",0); // you can set default size as you want
  }
}
```

Now In your `activity` do the following.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // initialize your text view here
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1); // add this line here and remove from `CreateAlertDialogWhitRadioGroupButton`

    // set text size from preference
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, SessionManager.getInstance(this).getTextSize());

    button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CreateAlertDialogWhitRadioGroupButton();
        }

    });


}

public void CreateAlertDialogWhitRadioGroupButton() {

    Context context;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Title text");
    // remove below line and add it inside the onCreate
    //textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(values, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            int textSize = 0;
            switch (item) {
                case 0:
                    textSize = 20;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    textSize = 30;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    textSize = 40;
                    break;
            }
            // set text size to your textview.
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSize);
            // save your text size to preference
            SessionManager.getInstance(YourActivityName.this).setTextSize(textSize)
            alertDialogTextSize.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialogTextSize = builder.create();
    alertDialogTextSize.show();
}
```

Comment: `textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, SessionManager.getInstance(this).getTextSize());` **error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to float** and `return prefs.getInt("text_size",0);` **error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String**

Comment: oops, it was my mistake. I have updated my answer see it now. I just changed the return type of `getTextSize()` method in `SessionManager` class.

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly instantiating the **SharedPreference** object. i.e You are using this

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

You have to use **getSharedPreferences** which takes two parameters

1. The SharedPrefs Filename
2. The mode in which you want to open the file

But you are passing only one parameter. So change it to like this

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And **getPreferences(int)** works different read more about it here ->

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences(int)

Comment: wherever you have written this SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); change it to SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences("SomeFileNameYouWant", MODE_PRIVATE); i.e in LoadPreferences() and SavePreferences()

Comment: Yes, I thought so, but it doesn't work, it reports a bug. Post screenshot, pls look.

Comment: use Context.MODE_PRIVATE  instead of just MODE_PRIVATE

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've tried it before and it's the same problem.

Comment: No problem, use getSharedPreferences() instead of getPreferences() now it will work